# Very small English 2 Pig Latin translator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure if `translate` produces 100% accurate Pig Latin. I was also wondering if this code is python 2.7 compatible and if its not what is broken?
Any advice on how to improve this would be appreciated.

```
def translate(text):
    return ' '.join('{}{}{}'.format(word, word[0], 'say')[1:] for word in text.split())

while 1:
    print(translate(input('Enter some words to translate: ')))
```

Comment: "I was also wondering if this code is python 2.7 compatible" have you tried running it on a 2.7 interpreter?

Comment: I don't have a version of 2.7 installed

Answer (score 1):

After running the code in repl.it ([here](https://repl.it/@rottencandy/BarrenRealGoa)), the only thing i had to change was,

```
print(translate(raw_input('Enter some words to translate: ')))
```

And it worked the same way as it did in python 3.